# Activate tracking using Kinect V2 in C++

Tags: c++, kinect, kinect-sdk

I recently started coding a Kinect in C++ using VS2013 and Kinect SDK 2.0. When I tried to get hand gestures after seeing code samples, I was unable to 'track' a body even after opening all necessary sources/streams (the Kinect, BodyFrameReader, etc.). So, my question is, does the Kinect automatically provide tracking? If not, then how do you enable/activate tracking of a particular object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I fixed a unnoticed error, I discovered that Kinect automatically does body tracking. To use it, just create the body stream and if the Kinect tracks a body, it would put it into the IBody* array that you created.